# JavaScript.Replace content wrapped in dollar signs ($) outside of HTML tags

Tags: javascript, regex

**note: I'm -not- trying to parse HTML with regex**

I'm trying to replace any content wrapped in $ signs ($for example$) in a string. I've managed to come up with `str.replace(/\$([^\$]*)\$/g), "hello $1!")`, but I'm having issues with making sure I don't replace such strings when they are wrapped in HTML tags.

Example string: `$someone$, <a>$welcome$</a>, and $another$`

Expression: `/[^>]\$([^\$]*)\$[^<]/g`

Expected output: `hello someone!, <a>$welcome</a>, and hello another!`

Actual output: `$someonhello , !elcomhello , and !nother$`

Test code: `alert("$someone$, <a>$welcome$</a>, and $another$".replace(/[^>]\$([^\$]*)\$[^<]/g, "hello $1!"));`

fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/WMWHZ/

Thanks!

Comment: i think we need to take a step back. How are you getting this text that you are parsing? What is the *real* problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: When you speak about content that is wrapped in HTML tags, you actually are talking about parsing HTML. Because how would you otherwise decide what is wrapped in HTML tags if not by parsing?

Comment: ... and wouldn't *every* text be wrapped in some HTML tag, actually?

Comment: I think he means _tightly_ wrapped, so it has just a text node as a child with a `nodeValue` beginning and ending with a '$'.

Comment: @mkoryak: I'm parsing a textarea that might contain HTML along with special text wrapped in $'s, which I will do something special to; A problems rises when I have such symbols inside HTML tags, which I don't want to touch.

MaxArt has it right, if I understood correctly. I could've rephrased the question to say "ignore stuff inside brackets" but I thought it would be better to keep it in context, as HTML tags are a popular discussion around regular expressions.

Thanks all btw!

Comment: @DvirAzulay Then you have to decide when something is inside an element and when it’s outside an element. And at that point you need an HTML parser.

Comment: What about `<a>text</a>$welcome$<a>more text</a>`? If you want to replace that one you will need a real parser.

Comment: @mcrumley: I see, that one indeed fails on MaxArt's answer, but I don't care too much about extra whitespace and can add extra whitespace before and after $ signs; though, I would love to know why it fails and why it is an unsolvable problem with a simple regex. Thanks a lot!

Comment: `<a>text</a>$welcome$<a>more text</a>` fails because the regular expression cannot tell the difference between the begin and end tags. `<br>$welcome$` will also fail because the regex doesn't know that `<br>` does not have and end tag. There many more ways that it can fail, but I don't have room to list them all here. If adding white space to work around these problems is OK then you can probably use a regular expression.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keep in mind that you have 6 '$' in your test case. The problem here is that when you try to check if the previous character isn't a '>', the regexp moves forward and matches what's between the **4th** and the **5th** dollar symbol, capturing `"</a>, and "` and making a mess.

Try this one:

```
$('div').text(test.replace(/(^|[^>])\$([^<][^\$]*)\$(?!<)/g, "$1hello $2!"))​
```

Javascript doesn't support lookbehinds in regular expressions, but it does support lookaheads (the `(?!<)` part). To emulate lookbehinds, you correctly tried to put `[^>]` before the dollar, but then the character is matched so you have to catch it and put it again in the string.

You just have to refine it a little, because if the '$' is at the beginning of the string, the group isn't captured.

Also, to avoid problems like the one above, you should check if there isn't a '<' *after* the first dollar, so I put a `[^<]` at the beginning of the capturing group. This also mean that it won't catch empty strings between dollar symbols (as in '$$'), they must contain at least one character.

This way, you have the expected result.

Comment: The `(^|[^>])` group should be non-capturing `(?:^|[^>])` or you can capture unwanted spaces.

Comment: You have to capture it so you can put it back in in the replacement string. Otherwise the `>` gets removed.

Comment: @mcrumley: your regex doesn't work against `<p>$someone$, <a>$welcome$</a>, and $another$</p>`.

Comment: Assuming that you can have arbitrary nesting, I would use this: (^|[^>])\$[^\$<>]*\$(?!<).

Comment: @MaxArt: This is awesome! Thanks, it is almost perfect!
Though, I'm having an issue with a string like `$alpha$$beta$` where only the alpha gets treated. I can work-around it by adding whitespace in such cases, as it won't matter too much for me, but I wondered if that can be solved as well!

And thanks again!

Comment: Oh, and maybe I should add that I won't need to treat cases of $$ nesting.

Comment: @DvirAzulay: I don't think `$alpha$$beta$` is possible without lookbehinds.

Comment: @MarkM: It's not MY regex :-) But you are right. There are other cases it will not catch, too. Sometimes (usually) a real parser is the only correct solution.

Comment: @mcrumley: I agree 100%, but from the context presented in the OP it seemed that nesting would be a common scenario.  I try not to nitpick too much, regardless of my OCD tendencies. :-)

Comment: Alrighty then; I've settled on adding whitespaces before and after $ prior to replacing, which solves all of my current problems without interfering with the solution.
Can't express how useful, fast, and responsive you all were. Thanks a lot!

Comment: A dollar sign inside of a character class will be treated literally without using an escaping character.